# Are logical operators in assertions acceptable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

What do you think about the following assertion?

```
Assert.IsTrue(condition1 && condition2);
```

I came up with this type of assertions during a review session. As far as I see using && operator in an assertion is not a good practice. I am wondering what others think? Is it worth  mentioning this is an issue during the next review sessions? Or it is just a personal preference?

Comment: And why do you feel that it's not a good idea?  What are you suggesting be done instead?

Comment: I feel nothing wrong in doing it...

Comment: Are the error messages clear when the tests fail?

Comment: I think this way the assert hides a bit of info if the test failes. Condition1 or condition2 were false? I d prefer two separate asserts with error messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write

```
Assert.IsTrue(condition1 && condition2);
```

Then it's not clear what caused test to fail - first or second condition. Thus you need both of them to be `true` just check one after another:

```
Assert.IsTrue(condition1);
Assert.IsTrue(condition2);
```

Now let's think what's wrong with OR conditions:

```
Assert.IsTrue(condition1 || condition2);
```

This looks like **random** test - it will pass in different scenarios:

1. first condition is true and second is false
2. if both are true
3. if second is true but first is false

So, what scenario you are checking exactly? Create three different scenarios which reproduce this three situations. Each tests will contain two asserts, e.g. for last scenario:

```
Assert.IsFalse(condition1);
Assert.IsTrue(condition2);
```

Comment: and an error message too, thats exactly what i mentioned at the review session.

Comment: @pappati yes, agree with you. Messages are also useful. Btw I updated answer with OR conditions

Comment: I think you're actually right about the '||', I can't think of any good example for what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context.

```
Assert.IsTrue(condition1 && condition2);
```

can of course be replace by 2 separate `Assert`s but how about

```
Assert.IsTrue(condition1 || condition2);
```

When that happens to be the valid test result then I see no problem with it.

So, when the 2 conditions are logically related, use an `&&`.
When they are 2 more or less independent outcomes, use 2 Assert calls.

Answer (score 2):

If the conditions are unrelated then I would make two assertions.  But your technique is very useful for

```
Debug.Assert(str != null && str.Length == 10);
```

because then that does not throw, as

```
Debug.Assert(str != null);
Debug.Assert(str.Length == 10);
```

would in the case where the assertion is violated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a unit test should test 1 and only 1 thing. Using && seems to be going against this.

If there are multiple 'concepts' or areas of concern then this isn't ideal and suggests refactoring to distinct tests, one per concept.

Alternatively, if it's just a bit of working-out logic then fine. But - extract this logic to make it explicit this is what is going on, rather than putting it in the assert.

> Does it make sense to split the test into more than one test?

- Is it possible for the split-out tests to fail independently?
- Will having another test give useful information to the person investigating the failure if it were to fail?
- Is the split out test testing something useful that has a chance of failure or is it trivial?
- Is is possible / easy to refactor to have multiple tests?